# Are some coupling tags synonyms?

Tags: support, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

There are the tags [coupling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coupling), [decoupling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decoupling), [tightly-coupled-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tightly-coupled-code), [decouple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decouple) and [loose-coupling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loose-coupling) where two or more might preferably be merged.

I was going to tag a question about coupling but I don't know which coupling tag to choose.

Comment: I would say that questions in [tag:decouple] could be retagged to [tag:decoupling] as a start.